# Get cross-domain iframe feedback

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a situation where I have an iframe hosting a third-party site.  I need to pick up only that the iframe has navigated to its final "success" url, so I can respond.

However, as you may know, modern browsers prevent you from accessing the iframe document object, even the location, because of CORS security issues.

Right now, I am running a counter in the onload event of the iframe, and performing my response when the counter hits a certain number.

But this is very hacky and won't be reliable enough for a new situation where I am having to use this mechanism.

So I'm looking for some wizard to tell me a better way.  I just need to know when it's reached a certain URL.

BTW jquery is not an option; this is an Angular2 app.

Thanks!
frood

Comment: Is the 3rd party in your (or someone you can talk to) control?  The only way you're going to make this work is if both the inner and outer page cooperate with each other.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Yes, it is something I can control

Answer (score 0):

If you control both parent and embedded websites (And don't have to support very old browsers) I would consider using the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). It enables simple event communication between the parent and the child.

Here is a nice simple example - [link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)